# How to show real link image from imported image in React?

Tags: reactjs

How is it possible to display the real link to the imported image in React?

Let's say I have a module like this:

```
import React from "react";

import image from "../assets/img/icons/image.png";

function Module() {
  return (
    <section>
      <span>Hello</span>
      <img src={image} alt="image" />
    </section>
  );
}

export default Module;
```

But instead of such an output, I would need the absolute path of the image.

```
<section>
    <span>Hello</span>
    <img
        src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAIAAAACACAYAAADDPmHL..."
        alt="image"
    />
</section>
```

How to do it please?

Comment: So you use from the absolute path, then what is the issue?

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi I don't want the src image format to appear in my output: data:image/png;base64,...

Comment: I think Arman means dont use import, just add the img path to the src="/assets/.. etc